# Spring with ElastiCache. Not able to instantiate AmazonElastiCacheClient error

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud

I am trying to write a basic hello app with Spring Cloud AWS to test out Redis through Elasticache support in Spring Cloud.
As soon as I add the following line to my configuration XML my build is failing.

```
<aws-cache:cache-manager>
        <aws-cache:cache-cluster name="CacheCluster" />
    </aws-cache:cache-manager>
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.beanFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonElastiCache': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.Class]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Class]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.amazonaws.services.elasticache.AmazonElastiCacheClient]
```

I tried explicity adding the dependency for AWS Elasticache libray into my POM, but only made it even worse.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-elasticache</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the error I am getting after the POM change.

```
Error creating bean with name 'springBootAwsApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate base.SpringBootAwsApplication.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springrds': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.beforeMarshalling(Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest;
```

This is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.nyn</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-aws</artifactId>
<version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>spring-boot-aws</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Cloud AWS</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <groupId>com.basho.riak</groupId>
        <artifactId>riak-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.resource</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-connector-api_1.5_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-tcp</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-elasticache</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.15</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is what I have in config.xml

```
    <aws-context:context-credentials>
    <aws-context:simple-credentials
        access-key="$accesskey" secret-key="$secret" />
</aws-context:context-credentials>
<aws-context:context-region region="$region" />
<aws-jdbc:data-source 
    db-instance-identifier="$rdsid" password="$rdspassword">
    <aws-jdbc:pool-attributes initialSize="1" defaultCatalog="Records"
                      testOnBorrow="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" />
</aws-jdbc:data-source>
<aws-cache:cache-manager>
    <aws-cache:cache-cluster name="CacheCluster" />
</aws-cache:cache-manager>
```

And here is my main() class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:aws-config.xml")

public class SpringBootAwsApplication {

@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAwsApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

Poking around it further, I am now stuck with this error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonElastiCache': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.amazonaws.services.elasticache.AmazonElastiCacheClient]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: requestHandlers
```

which basically says it can't create a bean named `amazonElastiCache` with an error in constructor which is missing a field `requestHandlers`.
Can anybody tell me how to properly instantiate `amazonElastiCache` ?

Comment: maybe try with some help of spel: `<aws-cache:cache-cluster name="#{ T(java.lang.Class).forName('CacheCluster')}"/>`

Comment: Didn't change a thing. :(

Comment: The exception is about the RDS/JdbcTemplate, not the ElastiCache. You should resolve the JDBC incompatibility by following the http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html guide. But to be honest: If you "just" need MySQL and Redis, it's easier to integrated these services using Spring Data Redis and the plain JDBC template :-)

Comment: I thought the same initially. But if you look at the last error message I have posted, it clearly is because of ElastiCache. Basically, I have no clue how to autowire, or instantiate the Elasticache factory (or whatever it should be). I have no guide/tutorial available online. :(

Comment: You might be hitting some variation of this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/124.  I do have ElastiCache working using Spring Session using the fix listed in the GitHub issue.

Comment: @ccit-spence That thread was little too advanced for me. Is there any chance I can find a simple "hello world" level sample of Spring+AWS+RDS+Elasticache. The moment I add elasticache to the setup (already has RDS/JDBC), I get a lot of autowiring related errors. My JDBC wirings fail. I am not able to find a way out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136013/spring-cloud-with-rds-hello-world

Answer (score 0):

Use a newer dependency version of `aws-java-sdk-elasticache`. The vanilla setup brings the version `1.9.27` whereas your specified version is `1.9.15`.

I tried your code and it worked for me with the following dependency:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-elasticache</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.11</version>
</dependency>
```

HTH, Mark.

Comment: I tried this. Now, the errors are turned over to the JDBC related @autowiring. It is not able to bind the JdbcTemplate with the object. Looks like there is some sort of conflict between Elasticache and Rds modules in aws, in my project.