# Spring cloud with RDS, hello world

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, rds

I am newbie to Spring Cloud and wanted to write a simple "hello world" RDS program.

My configuration is stored in the xml config as follows.

```
<aws-context:context-credentials>
    ...
</aws-context:context-credentials>
<aws-context:context-region region="ap-southeast-1" />

<jdbc:data-source db-instance-identifier="amazonrds"
    password="${password}" read-replica-support="false">
    <jdbc:pool-attributes initialSize="1"
        defaultCatalog="Records" testOnBorrow="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" />
</jdbc:data-source>
```

And I have a simple DB service class which reads like this.

```
@Service
public class JdbcRecordService implements RecordService {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public JdbcRecordService(DataSource datasource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Record> all() {
        return this.jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM Records", new RowMapper<Record>() {
            @Override
            public Record mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return new Record(resultSet.getString("Name"), resultSet.getString("Value"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void store(Record record) {
        this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO Records(Name, Value) VALUES (?,?)", record.getKey(), record.getValue());
    }
}
```

And the Application class is like this.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource("classpath:aws-config.xml")
public class SpringBootAwsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAwsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I know I am missing some connectors here, but I can't figure out what it is. Currently it throws this error, when building.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcRecordService' defined in file [C:\Users\codev\gitlab\springaws\target\classes\base\rds\JdbcRecordService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

It basically says, there is no bean candidate that can autowire the construction with a DataSource parameter. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**:My issue got fixed just by re-ordering the depending in my POM.xml. I still don't know which specific dependency conflict caused this issue but just moving `aws-java-sdk` to the top of the dependency list fixed my issues.

Comment: try to make a typo in aws-config.xml if spring read it or not

Comment: It is read. I get xml errors when I have something wrong there.

Comment: @Codevalley you have to create bean for jdbcTemplate before autowiring it.